# Google Maps API Geocode gives error "Invalid label" in Firefox

Tags: google-maps, label, geocode

Today I struggled with the following:

```
$.ajax({url:'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/jsonaddress=Karachi&sensor=false&output=json&callback=?',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
         //eval("("+data+")");
         alert(data);
        }
});
```

Firefox gives the error "Invalid Label" and Chrome "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :". I found a lot of posts about this, and I tried all kinds of things like eval(), but also:

```
$.getJSON('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/jsonaddress=Karachi&sensor=false&output=json&callback=?',
 function(data){
  //eval("("+data+")");
  alert(data);
 }
);
```

Same result. Also, other json data works fine, for instance flickr ("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?). So it has something to do with the Google Maps API output i guess..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There should be a questionmark in between json and address ("geocode/json?address=whatever")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just can't do it; AFAIK Geocoder V3 does not allow `callback=?`.
Check [this](http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-api/browse_thread/thread/302de895b1240ff5/338359be5dae302b?lnk=gst&q=callback#338359be5dae302b) thread for further information.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but Google DOES send back the JSON data. I can see it in Firebug. Also callback= is filled in, in my case: jsonp1271887454223. So that works..

Comment: Anyway, I now fixed it with help of this tut: http://www.developer.com/db/article.php/10920_3621981_2/Performing-HTTP-Geocoding-with-the-Google-Maps-API.htm. It's kinda slow and xml instead of json, but works in my case. Thanks!

Comment: @Benny JSON is returned but not wrapped in jsonp1271887454223() and firefox raises "invalid label" error.You could use callback but with V2 (deprecated) i think.

Comment: Yeah, i think the tut i followed used v2.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in maps V3, but you can't use $.getJSON to get the data, instead there is a method in the maps api which retrives the data if you give it an address.

```
var  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
 geocoder.geocode( { 'address': '10 downing street, London, UK'}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        console.log(results);
        alert(results[0].geometry.location);

      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
```

these links have all the info....
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingRequests

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple